# How to create a Node.js module from Asynchronous Function response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, module, node-modules

This problem is in regards the creation of a Node module that depends on a async function to return the content. For instance, "src/index.js" is the following:

### GOAL

The module A, implemented from "src/index" must be resolved and must not depend on promises, or anything else... It will just return a JSON object of computed values.

```
var a = require("./src/index");
// should be resolved already.
console.log(a.APP_NAME)
```

### src/index.js

```
"use strict";
var CoreClass = require("./core-class");

var coreInstance = new CoreClass();

coreInstance.toJson(function(err, coreData) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error while loading " + __filename);
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  console.log(coreData);
  // Export the data from the core.
  module.exports = coreData;
});
```

### src/core-class.js

The implementation of the method "toJson()", defined in the class in the file "src/core-class.js" is as follows:

```
/**
 * @return {string} Overriding the toStrng to return the object properties.
 */
ISPCore.prototype.toJson = function toJson(callback) {
  var result = {
    // From package.json
    APP_NAME: this.appPackageJson.name.trim(),
    APP_VERSION: this.appPackageJson.version.trim(),
    APP_CONFIG_DIR: this.APP_DIR + "/config",
    APP_DOCS_DIR: this.APP_DIR + "/docs",
    APP_TESTS_DIR: this.APP_DIR + "/tests",
  };

  // TODO: Remove this when we have a registry
  if (!this.pom) {
    // Let's verify if there's a pom.xml file in the roort APP_DIR
    var _this = this;
    this.APP_POM_PATH = this.APP_DIR + "/pom.xml";

    // Check first to see if the file exists
    fs.stat(this.APP_POM_PATH, function(err, fileStats) {
      // The file does not exist, so we can continue with the current result.
      if (err) {
        return callback(null, result);
      }
      _this._loadPomXmlSettings(function pomXmlCallback(err, pomObject) {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err);
        }

        _this.pom = pomObject;
        // Update the result with the pom information
        result.POM_GROUPID = _this.pom.groupid || "undefined";
        result.POM_ARTIFACTID = _this.pom.artifactid || "undefined";
        result.POM_VERSION = _this.pom.version || "undefined";

        // Callback with the updated version.
        return callback(null, result);
      });

    });

  } else {
    result.POM_GROUPID = this.pom.groupid || "undefined";
    result.POM_ARTIFACTID = this.pom.artifactId || "undefined";
    result.POM_VERSION = this.pom.version || "undefined";

    // Return just what's been collected so far, including the pom.
    return callback(null, result);
  }
};
```

### Test class

Requiring this and trying to use the library just returns an empty object. Here's the test class...

```
  // describing the method to get the instance.
  describe("require(sp-core) with pom.xml", function() {

    var core = null;

    before(function(done) {
      // Copy the fixture pom.xml to the APP_DIR
      fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/../pom.xml", fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/fixture/pom.xml"));
      // Load the library after the creation of the pom
      core = require("../src/");
      console.log("TEST AFTER CORE");
      console.log(core);

      done();
    });

    after(function(done) {
      // Delete the pom.xml from the path
      fs.unlinkSync(__dirname + "/../pom.xml");

      done();
    });

    it("should load the properties with pom properties", function(done) {
      expect(core).to.be.an("object");
      console.log("Loaded pom.xml metadata");
      console.log(core);
      expect(core.POM_ARTIFACTID).to.exist;
      expect(core.POM_VERSION).to.exist;

      done();
    });
  });
```

### Execution of the tests

However, after a while, the output from the library shows up in the console.

```
  SPCore with pom.xml
    require(sp-core) with pom.xml
TEST AFTER CORE
{}
Loaded pom.xml metadata
{}
      1) should load the properties with pom properties
{ APP_NAME: 'sp-core',
  APP_VERSION: '0.3.5',
  ENV: 'development',
  NODE_ENV: 'development',
  IS_PROD: false,
  APP_DIR: '/home/mdesales/dev/isp/sp-core',
  APP_CONFIG_DIR: '/home/mdesales/dev/isp/sp-core/config',
  APP_DOCS_DIR: '/home/mdesales/dev/isp/sp-core/docs',
  APP_TESTS_DIR: '/home/mdesales/dev/isp/sp-core/tests',
  POM_GROUPID: 'com.mycompany',
  POM_ARTIFACTID: 'my-service',
  POM_VERSION: '1.0.15-SNAPSHOT' }


  0 passing (142ms)
  1 failing

  1) SPCore with pom.xml require(sp-core) with pom.xml should load the properties with pom properties:
     AssertionError: expected undefined to exist
```

### How to properly create a module that depends on an Async call?

I'm sure this is due to the asynchronous call, but I was thinking that the module would not return {}, but wait until the callback returns.

I tried using:

- Async.waterfall
- Deasync (does not work)

### Async.waterfall attempt

```
"use strict";

var async = require("async");
var CoreClass = require("./core-class");
var coreInstance = new CoreClass();

async.waterfall([
  function(cb) {
    coreInstance.toJson(cb);
  },
  function(coreData) {
    console.log(coreData);
    module.exports = coreData;
  }
]);
```

Please please help!

Comment: Export a promise from your `src/index.js` file

Comment: Show  me te code you tried with waterfall

Comment: @Gepser, I added the code to the end of the description. The output is the same as "Execution of the tests".

Comment: Thanks, that's enough for me to reproduce and trying to get the goal

Comment: @Gepser that would be awesome... The code worked at some point... I'm not sure what I did to break it... I spent the entire day today on it, and I could get the test cases to pass... However, I was trying to refact it further and I'm not sure what happened... :( I can't see where exactly the problem is... :(

Comment: Your goal as stated is impossible.  The only way this could have worked in the past is if `toJson` wasn't actually asynchronous.  It is possible to export the object your looking for (rather than the empty object you're seeing now), but it won't be available immediately.

Comment: @AaronDufour :( Ok, I will return the object with the functions that users would have to call in order to retrieve the async values later :( Thanks for the comment. I needed the value to be available immediately.

Comment: I reproduced your problem almost exactly and @AaronDufour is right, what you are trying is not possible. The exact problem is when you try to use something exported from your module, i.e. `console.log(a.APP_NAME)`, then the app neither waits or crashes, it just assign `undefined` to the requested value.

Comment: @AaronDufour I found a solution with "deasync" module. :) It works... See solution below!!!

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, I revisited the attempt of using "deasync" module, and it WORKS! YES WE CAN! Cheating with the hack of "deasync" :D

### Runnable instance

The runnable solution is at http://code.runnable.com/VbCksvKBUC4xu3rd/demo-that-an-async-method-can-be-returned-before-a-module-exports-is-resolved-for-node-js-deasync-pom-parser-and-stackoverflow-31577688

- Type "npm test" in the terminal box and hit "ENTER" (always works).
- Just click in the "Run" button to see the execution of the code. All the source code is available. (Sometimes the container gets corrupted and the test fails).

### Solution

Here's the implementation of the "GOAL" module.

```
/** @module Default Settings */

"use strict";
var CoreClass = require("./core-class");
var merge = require("merge");
var deasync = require("deasync");

// Core properties needed.
var coreInstance = new CoreClass();
var coreProperties = coreInstance.toJson();

// Pom properties temporary support, deasync the async call
var loadPom = deasync(coreInstance.loadPomXmlSettings);
var pomObject = loadPom(coreProperties.APP_POM_PATH);

// Merge them all.
var allProperties = merge(coreProperties, pomObject);

module.exports = allProperties;
```

With that, all the code is returned as expected for the module.exports!

Comment: That is a nice solution!